# How to set tab for all files to use two spaces when in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

When I edit ruby (.`rb`) and Javascript (`.js`) files my settings seem to work ok to make a tab be a space.

However for other files, such as files with no extension, when I use tab I get a tab, not two spaces.

For the Ruby and js files I have:

```
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

I tried adding:

```
autocmd * javascript setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

and I also have the lines:

```
set tabstop=2 " What the tab key does, i.e. 2 spaces instead of tab
set shiftwidth=2 "What is used for indentation
set expandtab
```

but none of them are making my tab key actualy use two spaces in files other than ruby and js

How to make the tab being two spaces be universal?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
filetype indent on
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

Comment: Thanks guillermo Unfortunately that didn't help me.  I must have something else interfering, though I've tried disabling most things that could be culprits, like in my .vimrc for example.